# In Amadeus self service APIs, is price.total inclusive of all taxes and fees?

Tags: amadeus

For the Amadeus self-service rest APIs: v1/shopping/flight-offers and flight-dates, is the price.total response field inclusive of all taxes and fees?

I seem to need to add total + totalTaxes to get a price that's close to the one provided by the airline directly.

If there are developer docs that explain in more detail each response field, please do point me to them. I have been unable to find any.

In reference to these APIs:

https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/203/api-doc/4/api-docs-and-example/10002
https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/203/api-doc/5/api-docs-and-example/10003

and this field:

```
"price": {
  "total": "259.91",
  "totalTaxes": "185.91"
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“total” is the total price you will have to pay, it includes the totalTaxes.

You can access the model directly on Swagger (*under the Response Class (Status 200)*) you have the Model button. But you are right the description of those parameters need to be added, point taken.

Comment: Thanks so much Anthony for the fast response, and helpful pointer. Fantastic. In that case, the same flight is often quite a bit cheaper on Amadeus than the retail price on the airline's site. $436.88 vs $491.50 for this SFO to WLG test case: https://gist.github.com/chan1/ca8b9e5b342e8c71e225ec8182c041f7 vs https://imgur.com/a/r4HUd8I

Answer (score 1):

As highlighted in the accepted answer, the total price is the total including all taxes, personally, I was also initially confused and had to manually check with a travel agent to confirm. I would suggest Amadeus splits the description as follows

```
"price": {
  "totalFare": "74.00",
  "totalTaxes": "185.91"
  "totalAmount": "259.91"
},
```